# Calculating the expected gain in St. Petersburg Paradox

Tags: probability, paradoxes

I'd like to understand why can't we calculate the expected gain in [St. Petersburg paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox) as follows.

Let $G$ denote our gain and let $R$ denote the number of rounds that game proceeds. Then we have,
$$ G = 2^{R-1} .$$

In this case, can't we calculate our expected gain as,
$$ E[G] = 2^{E[R] -1} ?$$

If we have a fair coin, we simply have $ E[R] = 2 $ which gives us $E[G] = 2$.

So, it doesn't make sense to pay more than $2$ according to my calculation.
What's wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: What makes you think that $\mathbb E2^{R-1}=2^{\mathbb E(R-1)}$? That is not the case.

Comment: Oh. What's the proper way to compute expected value in this case then ?

Comment: For that see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox#The_paradox).

Comment: Ah I see the problem in my reasoning now. Thank you :)

Comment: Expected gain calculations simply do not work that way.  Let's take a simpler example.  I will throw an ordinary six-sided die.  If the result shows $n$ pips, you get paid $2^n$ dollars.  The expected number of pips is $\frac16(1+2+3+4+5+6) = \frac{21}6$.  Is the expected payoff $2^{21/6}\approx \$11.31$?  No, it is not.  It is $\frac16(2+4+8+16+32+64) = \$21.00$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just take the expectations of $G$ and $R$ and expect the formula to hold.  The definition of $E[G]$ is $\sum G\cdot P(G)$, which does not converge.  As an example, let us consider a modified game with $n$ rounds.  If keep succeeding and get to $n$ rounds you stop and are paid $2^{n-1}$.  Now the sums are finite.  $E[R]$ doesn't change much.  It is reduced below $2$ by a tiny amount.  If you do the sum, the expected value is just about $0.5n$, increased slightly because of the higher chance of stopping at $n$.

Answer (score 3):

It is not true in general that $\mathbb Ef(X)=f(\mathbb EX)$ as you seem to think.